# Detect all URLs and make them clickable, plus wrap images in <img> tag JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a JSON feed from a google spreadsheet.

In it are:

- Website URLs; and,
- Image URLs that end in jpg, jpeg, png and jfif.

Below this script turns all URLS into clickable links. Which works fine.
I would also like that the all the images get wrapped in a  tag.

```
//Parse all URLs to links
$(function() {
  $('.box-table').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a class=abbr href="$1">$1</a> '));
  });
})
```

This is my rather poor attempt to wrap all images in a  tag.

```
//Parse all URLs to links
$(function() {
  $('.box-table').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<img class=abbr" src="$1">$1</img> '));
  });
})
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using same regex for images? You need to detect it extension, so the regex won't be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the element from within the DOM as opposed to inserting a string directly into the page. A nice and neat way to do this in JQuery, with an image for example, would be as such:

```
$('<img />', { src: 'SRC_URL', class: 'abr' });
```

You can assign this to a variable and simply insert it into a dom node using `insertAfter`, `append` or any function that allows node manipulation.

Just for your information, vanilla JS offers a much nicer image instantiation process:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'myImageUrl';
img.onLoad = function() {
 // image loaded
}
```

Back to jQuery... 
If you wanted to nest the `img` tag inside a `div` node, you can do so with the following:

```
$('<div />', { class: 'parent-div'} ).append(
    $('<img>', { src: 'SRC_URL', class: 'abr' })
);
```

You can also assign this to a variable and you will have a `div` tag with a nested `img` tag.

Using your code, we would end up with something like this (untested, it assumes your code works):

```
//Parse all URLs to links
$(function() {
  $('.box-table').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, jQuery('<img />', { class: "abbr" src: "$1" }));
  });
})
```